# how to show data on mouse over in datagrid

Tags: silverlight-4.0

i have an Datagrid  lets  say i have columns  with name, age, mail ID. so all the details should  be  shown in a **pop up or some thing like  side  also will do**.

is there any thing like an slide  control so that once i make a mouse over the  row   i display that row  values in silde?

i need  to  show an pop up with details  what i have  displayed  in that  row.

how can i achive this functionality here. right now  binding values to datagrid is  done this  functioanlity is done.
 **how can  i  go ahead  to get an  solution  to  show  pop up on mouse  over**. any help   on this  issue  would be  really great and  help fully. i am new  to silver light concept

plz provide an solution on this.

thanks in advance

prince